# How can I change my nationality in my PayPal account without having to open a new one?

Tags: paypal

Is there any way to change one's nationality in a PayPal account without having to open a new one?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer from Paypal's Customer Support:

> ---------- Forwarded message ---------- 
>   From: Paypal support 
>   Subject: RE: Re: Questions About Address Changes
>
> Dear Franck Dernoncourt,
>
> Thank you for contacting PayPal. My name is Charles and I can understand the urgency and importance of this matter. Allow me to help you on this.
>
> Please note that in order **to change the nationality, you’ll have to
>   close the existing PayPal account and then create a new one** and
>   selecting the nationality during the sign-up process.
>
> Before you close your account please remove your financial details.
>   Here's how to remove your financial details:
>
> Go to 'Profile' and select 'My Money'. Depending on what information
>   you want to remove, click 'Update' in the relevant section. On the
>   next page, select the information you want removed and click 'Remove'.
>
> Here’s how to close your old PayPal account:
>
> Log into your PayPal account at www.paypal.com Click 'Profile' near
>   the top of the page. Select 'My Settings'. In the 'Account Type'
>   section, click 'Close account' and follow the instructions.
>
> After you close your account, any transactions that are in progress
>   are cancelled.
>
> Here’s how to create a new PayPal account:
>
> Go to www.paypal.com Click ‘Sign Up’ at the top of the page. Select
>   your country or region and your language. Select the type of account
>   you want to create, and then click ‘Get Started.’ Enter your
>   information, and then click ‘Agree and Create Account.’
>
> After you have confirmed your email address, you can use your new
>   account.
>
> We recommend that you add a credit card that was issued by a bank in
>   the same country as the country on your PayPal account.
>
> Yours sincerely,  Charles  PayPal
>
> Copyright © 1999-2013 PayPal. All rights reserved.
>
> PayPal (Europe) S.à r.l. et Cie, S.C.A. Société en Commandite par
>   Actions Registered Office: 22-24 Boulevard Royal L-2449, Luxembourg
>   RCS Luxembourg B 118 349

I closed my Paypal account and now use http://venmo.com, which is much easier to exchange money with friends.

Comment: "*to change the nationality, you’ll have to close the existing PayPal account and then create a new one*" and it's not a joke, unfortunately.

Comment: it is also strange that you have to specify the nationality, and not the country of residence.

Answer (score 8):

As far as I know, this is completely impossible.

I have just run into the same issue, and browsed by PayPal account's settings thoroughly. I found not even a trace of something that would all changing nationality (you can, of course change currency, but this is not the case here).

You may try to contact PayPal's support, but I fear, that you've already answered yourself and that closing current account and opening new one, under new nationality is the only option.